# Will reflection keeps the semantics of volatile in java

Tags: java, reflection, volatile

For example, when I modified a volatile field in one thread, the JMM would guarantee that then the new value will be visible to the other thread.

My question is, is this still true when I use reflection to modify the field?

The following code is just an example to show how reflection works.

```
public class ReflectionDemo {
    private volatile boolean flag = false;

    public static void modify(ReflectionDemo target, boolean value) {
        try {
            Field field = ReflectionDemo.class.getDeclaredField("flag");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.setBoolean(target, value);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReflectionDemo demo = new ReflectionDemo();
        System.out.println(demo.flag);

        ReflectionDemo.modify(demo, true);
        System.out.println(demo.flag);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, Only using `Unsafe` can you change volatile semantics.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  In another word, the `Unsafe` API don't care weather the field is modified by the volatile or not. When I use `putXXVolatile()` I got volatile semantics guarantee, when I use `putXX()` I got nothing. Is this true?

Comment: @PeterLawrey And does this this defined in _The Java Language Specification_ or _The Java Virtual Machine Specification_? I wanna  learn a little more about this question.

Comment: The operation chooses the semantics. Reflection generates byte code to perform the action for you in an efficient manner, but the access is still the same.

Comment: The JLS doesn't define the behaviour of any individual library, only the Javadoc does.

Answer (score 2):

*Extracted from the comments*

Yes, changes to a `volatile` field via reflection will be visible to other threads just like a standard access. This is because the reflection API generates JVM byte code to perform the actions, thus access to the field itself is still volatile.

The only way to violate the volatile semantics is via the `sun.misc.Unsafe` API.